# google position checker script php

Tags: php, web-analytics

does anyone here knows where can i find a script that can show me which position is my site in some keyword?

I'm looking for a script that can search in all 100 pages Google have for every keywords.

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you sure Google's Terms of Service allows this?

Answer (score 1):

This script will automatically track your websites’ Google positions for any given keywords on any Google (.co.uk, .com, .nl, .it etc). It will periodically update the rankings once a day and these can be easily displayed anywhere on your website.

Link [here](http://codecanyon.net/item/php-google-position-checker/239429?ref=svoloth)!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor your site use [Google Web master tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)

Google Webmaster Tools provides you with detailed reports about your pages' visibility on Google